# Ошибка при слиянии двух отсортированных массивов

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка

Пытаюсь реализовать слияние двух отсортированных массивов на java. Смотрел примеры тут, но некоторые выдают исключение из-за выхода за пределы индексации массива. Сделал свою реализацию, вот пример:

```
public int[] union(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB){
    int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length+arrayB.length];
    int indexA = 0;
    int indexB = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<arrayC.length; i++){
        if(indexA<=arrayA.length-1 & indexB<=arrayB.length-1){
            if(arrayA[indexA]<arrayB[indexB]){
                arrayC[i]=arrayA[indexA];
                indexA++;
            }else {
                arrayC[i]=arrayB[indexB];
                indexB++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayC;
}`
```

Тестирую:

```
public class Arrays_test{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int[] mass =  {12,0,16,26,6,5,3,199,13,44,32,43,18,2};
        int[] mass1 = {4,1,295,35,184,19,64,198,55,145,14,10,45,30};
        Array w = new Array();
        w.sort(mass);
        w.sort(mass1);
        w.printer(mass);
        System.out.println("");
        w.printer(mass1);
        System.out.println("");
        int[] result = w.union(mass, mass1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
```

При этом выводит следующее:

> 0 2 3 5 6 12 13 16 18 26 32 43 44 199
>
> 1 4 10 14 19 30 35 45 55 64 145 184 198 295
>
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19, 26, 30, 32, 35, 43, 44, 45, 55, 64, 145, 184, 198, 199, 0]

Почему последнее значение 0?
И если, например, уменьшить исходные массивы до 5 элементов то выдает следующее:

> 0 6 12 16 26
>
> 1 4 35 184 295
>
> [0, 1, 4, 6, 12, 16, 26, 0, 0, 0]

Почему оставшиеся элементы заполнились нулями?

Comment: `if(indexA<=arrayA.length-1 & indexB<=arrayB.length-1){...}`  Как только вы дайдете до конца одного из массивов, ваш алгоритм дальше уже ничего не делает.

Comment: Ага, я понял. Тогда не понятно, как не выйти за пределы индексации исходных массивов, когда на последнем элементе прибавляем единицу к индексу?

Comment: Мне проще было ответ написать, чем пояснять :) Надеюсь, идея ясна. В вашем варианте даже счетчик `i`, котрым вы пишете в результат `arrayC[i]` считает строгр до конца первого массива `for(int i=0; i<arrayC.length; i++)`, но ведь результат слияния 2  непустых массивов больше, чем каждый из массивов по отдельности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if(indexA<=arrayA.length-1 & indexB<=arrayB.length-1){...}

Как только вы дайдете до конца одного из массивов, ваш алгоритм дальше уже ничего не делает.

Простой пример реализации вашего алгоритма

```
public static int[] union(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB){
    int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length+arrayB.length];
    int indexA = 0;
    int indexB = 0;
    int indexC = 0;

    while (indexA < arrayA.length || indexB < arrayB.length)
    {
        if (indexA < arrayA.length && (indexB >= arrayB.length || arrayA[indexA] <= arrayB[indexB]))
        {
            arrayC[indexC] = arrayA[indexA];
            indexA++;
            indexC++;
        }

        if (indexB < arrayB.length && (indexA >= arrayA.length || arrayB[indexB] <= arrayA[indexA]))
        {
            arrayC[indexC] = arrayB[indexB];
            indexB++;
            indexC++;
        }
    }
    return arrayC;
}
```

Проверка

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] mass =  {12,0,16,26,6,5,3,199,13,44,32,43,18,2};
    int[] mass1 = {4,1,295,35,184,19,64,198,55,145,14,10,45,30};

    Arrays.sort(mass);
    Arrays.sort(mass1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass1));

    System.out.println("");
    int[] result = union(mass, mass1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Результат

```
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 12, 13, 16, 18, 26, 32, 43, 44, 199]
[1, 4, 10, 14, 19, 30, 35, 45, 55, 64, 145, 184, 198, 295]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19, 26, 30, 32, 35, 43, 44, 45, 55, 64, 145, 184, 198, 199, 295]
```

Comment: `while (indexA < arrayA.length || indexB < arrayB.length)` Я правильно понимаю, что эта строчка значит "цикл крутится пока хотя бы одно выражение true"? В любом случае спасибо за развернутый ответ. Буду сидеть разбираться в этих бесчисленных "или".

Comment: @XJlAMuD да, цикл крутится пока хотя бы один массив не пройден до конца. То есть, чтобы закончить цикл, найдо дойти до конца на обоих массивах.

Comment: @XJlAMuD если проблема исчерпана, выберете один из ответов, который по вашему мнению решает вашу проблему, и отметье его галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас такой сложный алгоритм? почему вы просто не копируете два массива в один, а потом не сортируете? мало того, копирование лучше не выполнять вручную. все дело в том, что ряд методов у джавы нативные, т.е.выполняются на низком уровне, как следствие, очень быстро, в т.ч. метод System.arraycopy. Посему лучше сделать так:

```
public int[] union(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int[] arrayC = new int[arrayA.length + arrayB.length];
    System.arraycopy(arrayA, 0, arrayC, 0, arrayA.length);
    System.arraycopy(arrayB, 0, arrayC, arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
    java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(arrayC);
    return arrayC;
}
```

Comment: Да, это безусловно проще и про нативные методы я знаю. Я сейчас вначале пути по изучению программирования и пытаюсь самостоятельно решать задачи, которые сам перед собой ставлю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще сделать - не обязательно свой алгоритм писать, а отсортировать можно после слияния, а не перед:

```
int[] mass = {12,0,16,26,6,5,3,199,13,44,32,43,18,2};
int[] mass1 = {4,1,295,35,184,19,64,198,55,145,14,10,45,30};

int length = mass.length;
int length1 = mass1.length;

int[] mass2 = new int[length + length1];

System.arraycopy(mass, 0, mass2, 0, length);
System.arraycopy(mass1, 0, mass2, length, length1);

Arrays.sort(mass2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass2));

// 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,13,14,16,18,19,26,30,32,35,43,44,45,55,64,145,184,198,199,295
```